# Increment a Y and X axis Unity C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

How can i possibly increment a Y axis in c#

For Example i have this data(prefab)

`P = Player
 B = Boss
 T = Travern`

This is shown like this :

[image]

What currently i can do in my code:

```
GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road[0]) as GameObject;
            o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road[0]);
            o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(2.0f,-5.0f,0f);
            //o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * xl, y * yl, 0f);

            if (allchars.Contains(playerwinnopairboth))
            {
                o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
                NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
            }
            if (allchars.Contains(bankerwinnopairboth))
            {
                o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
                NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
            }
```

is this

[image]

They are all in one spot. Could someone please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer . Here's what i did.

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 6];

string newPreviousValue = "placeholder";
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;

if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (previousValue.Equals(newPreviousValue) && yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1)
            {
                yIndex += 1;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
            }
            else
            {
                xIndex += 1;
                yIndex = 0;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
            }
            newPreviousValue = previousValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 o.transform.localPosition=new Vector3 (o.transform.localPosition.x,o.transform.localPosition.y+i,o.transform.localPosition.z);
```

Should increment only the y axis by i;

Comment: What's your i here sir?

Comment: i is the value you have to increment y by.

Comment: but the problem here sir is that my data is is not in that order . sometimes is `B B B then P then T T and P P` for example like that.

Comment: You could use conditions based on your data and increment x, y or both together.

Comment: hmmm i'll upvote your answer for now sir. But thanks anyway . :)