# check if the string is contain with matching string property

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

For example i have this data :

```
P, P, P, B, B, T, T, T, P, P
```

then i get it from doing it like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
{
    newString[0] += gametable_history_list[i].r;
    newString[0] += ",";
}
string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',');
```

What i want here is to detect if the data has the same character now for example like this

```
if(newChars isnot changing character){
```

Display: `P, P, P`

`else if(newChars is changing now){`

Display: `B,B`

`else if(newChars is changing now){`

Display: `T,T,T`

`else if(newChars is changing now){`

Display: `P,P`

It must be something like this Output:

[image]

What i am getting

[image]

My real problem here is that i need to `transform.localPosition` every the same data ( P, P, P) then if the data changes like (B, B) it must be move to another column which is i need to move the x and y axis.

Comment: Can you please confirm it is 2 or 3 'T' in third output?

Comment: @KaushalGosaliya Edited it . Sorry

Comment: from what i understand, you only want to show the characters that equal the *latest* charcacter, from the first occurrence inside that group until the end, correct?

Comment: @TimothyGroote Something like that sir

Comment: Can you show exactly what output you would expect to get.

Comment: @PaulF I edit my question sir. Added some info's

Comment: so, you want this data in a 2d array?

Comment: @TimothyGroote 2d array no sir.

Comment: then how do you intend to display this data like the picture of the table you provided?

Comment: @TimothyGroote i displayed it like this sir `foreach (string allchars in newChars){` then uses a condition like `if(allchars.Contains(thiskindofchar)){display}`

Comment: It is very confusing trying to understand what you want - you display the output as a 2d array & say that is NOT what you want. The display does not match the characters in the original input - why are there 2 P, 1 B, 1 T, 3 P when your original data is 3 P, 2 B, 3 T, 2 P

Comment: @PaulF i think it relates to one of OPS earlier questions ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095725/increment-a-y-and-x-axis-unity-c-sharp

Comment: ACTUALLY SIR YES THIS IS RELATED TO THAT QUESTION . IM SORRY

Comment: i think i have a fairly close to working example for you now, and if you read carefully you will find that @Nandgopal 's answer suddenly makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (partial) example (i have no idea how you create the displayed text, or how it's positioned so i can only set up a very basic example with a comment telling you how to place them)

::update::

I found your previous question and added the code you provided together with Nand gopal's answer in this answer

```
//calling this with "PPPBBTTTPP" yields ["PPP","BB","TT","PP"]
//keep in mind that this is a separate method
//so it should go *outside* the create, initialise, and update methods

string[] GroupString(string inputString){
     string result = " ";
     foreach (var c in inputString)
     {
         result = result + (result.Last() == c ? "" : " ") + c;
     }
     return result.Trim().Split(' ');
}

//the logic for creating your table :

string newString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
{
    newString += gametable_history_list[i].r;
}

string[] groupedString = GroupString(newString);

//you can now iterate over groupedString

for(int x=0; x < groupedString.length; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y < groupedString[x].length; y++)
    {

        //display groupedString[x] at position determined using X and Y
        //(i don't know how you do this since you did not provide example code for this part)

        //update : assuming your previous question is related : 
        GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road[0]) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road[0]);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        //the positioning happens here : 
        o.transform.localPosition=new Vector3 (o.transform.localPosition.x+x,o.transform.localPosition.y+y,o.transform.localPosition.z);

        if (allchars.Contains(playerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }
        if (allchars.Contains(bankerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I left one thing for you to figure out :  i am not sure if Unit's Y-axis is inverted, so your table might render upside down.

Comment: woops. my bad. should be gone now.

Comment: I'll try this out sir . And i'll comeback to you. THanks

Comment: i changed it, this one does the same thing, but without Linq or fancy syntactic sugar.

Comment: Sir i accidentally upgraded from c# 4 to c# 7.0 . Is my project alright???? damn im nervous

Comment: @TheGinxx009 well that escalated quickly. i never tried that before, but my best guess is that C#7 code won't run on MONO, so i'd just try to change it back.

Comment: (you probably didn't ruin your project, you can just change the version back. and it looks like unity can do C#6 these days. exciting times!)

https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/

Comment: on a related note : since you tagged this question with android : don't try running .NET standard on android just yet. just stick with 4.x

Comment: o how can i change back to c# 4.0 sir i'm using visual studio 2017

Comment: by the way sir my all char is a `foreach` statement which is `foreach (string allchars in newChars){`

Comment: changing the C# version isn't hard ; https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St
you can replace the foreach with the for loop, or add a counter variable (whichever you prefer)

Comment: i can't reproduce what you are doing from here without seeing what you did. unfortunately "this does not work" isn't enough for me to go on. especially if i don't even know what you mean by "this" ;)